# Password protect a share folder on windows server 2012

Tags: password, file-server

How to add a password on a share folder on windows server 2012 that grants access to 2-3 people in the domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

joeqwerty is correct.  you cannot put in a password in normal windows.  This belongs in a 3rd party realm.  Such applications include: http://www.kakasoft.com/password-protect-shared-folder/How-to-Password-Protect-Network-Folder.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a password to a folder. You can assign NTFS permissions to the folder that allow only the appropriate user accounts to access the folder.